# Align list items in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have these 2 divs, and inside them, the 2  with some lists. What i want, is that the first div or ul content, is to be on the left side in the container div, and the second, to go to the right side of the container.

I tried giving the -s text-left and text-right classes, but nothing happend.

```
<div class="header_full_width">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="header_links_ul">
                    <li class="float-left"><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
                    <li class="float-left"><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
                    <li class="float-left"><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <ul class="header_links_ul">
                    <li class="float-left"><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
                    <li class="float-left"><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.header_full_width{ widows:100%; background:#fff; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
.header_links_ul{ list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.header_links_ul li { display:block; }
.header_links_ul li a{ color:#000; font-size:12px;  display:block;}
```

I get no error. You can see on the photo, what i want to do.
Thanks!

[image: Photo, click here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add flex display to your `.header_links_ul`div like this:

div to left add class:  `justify-content-start`

div to right add class: `justify-content-end`

```css
.header_full_width{ widows:100%; background:#fff; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
 li { list-style-type:none }
 li a{ color:#000; font-size:12px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header_full_width">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                <ul class=" d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
                    <li><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                <ul class= "d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
                    <li><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks good! And on mobile, how can i put these links under to each other? And should i change the col-md-6 divs to an another?

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help, it was usefull. And sorry for to many and idiot questions, but i am learning boottrap 4 and flex. Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `float-right` on second `col-md-6` `ul li`

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="header_links_ul">
     <li class="float-right"><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
     <li class="float-right"><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/kn23c8jp/2/

Comment: And can i do this without float classes, and you some flex things? This is bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS class float-left add style left:0 !important for Regisztráció.

Comment: Why? I dont understand. I want to move that to link in the second ul to the right side of the container div.

Comment: my bad! in that case do Right:0

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="header_full_width">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-md-left text-sm-center text-center">
                <ul class="header_links_ul">
                    <li><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-md-right text-sm-center text-center">
                <ul class="header_links_ul">
                    <li><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

`text-align` can do the work way more easily. Also you can alignment change on other views. I have kept centered align on small and extra small devices, you can check that out! Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

try this code simple

**HTML**

```
<div class="header_full_width"> 
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <ul class="header_links_ul">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <ul class="header_links_ul">
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.header_full_width{ widows:100%; background:#fff; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
.header_links_ul{ list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.header_links_ul li { display:block; }
.header_links_ul li a{ color:#000; font-size:12px;  display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flex

```css
.header_full_width{ widows:100%; background:#fff; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; }
.header_links_ul{ list-style:none; margin:0; padding:0;}
.header_links_ul li { display:block; }
.header_links_ul li a{ color:#000; font-size:12px;  display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="header_full_width">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul class="header_links_ul d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-start">
                    <li><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <ul class="header_links_ul d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-end">
                    <li><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```